# Having issue using for loop and array together

Tags: php

PHP: Here is what I am supposed to accomplish. And below is my code. I am definitely missing something..

Write a FOR loop using an array that prints “The product of first 10 numbers is ” followed by the product of numbers 1 through 10.  Here’s a hint: do NOT begin counter at 0 or else the product will be a zero!

```
<?php
$numbers = 0;
$numbers = range(1 , 10);
$arrlength = count($numbers);
for ($x = 1; $x <= $arrlength; $x++) {
$numbers[$x] = $numbers + $x;
}
echo "The product of first 10 numbers is $numbers.<br>";

?>
```

Comment: You seem to be using `$numbers` for two different purposes.  You should have two different variables, say `$numberSum` and `$numbers`.

Comment: I'm confused why an `array` is used in this question.

Comment: Sounds like an assignment. You wouldn't need an array for this task. If you really need an array you could use `array_sum` on it to calculate the sum. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

Comment: @cmorrissey I'm also confused why the result is being summed and not multiplied since the exercise asks for a product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially what you're doing is creating a factorial function for a limited case. The problems with your implementation are that you seemed to re-use the `$numbers` variable when it should be one variable to hold the product and one for the array 1-10. The second issue is in your loop where you loop from 1-10 but what you probably really want to do is loop from 0-9 which are the array indices so that you can get the values from the array like this:

```
<?php
$prod = 1;
$numbers = range(1 , 10);
$arrlength = count($numbers);
for ($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
     $prod *= $numbers[$x];
}
echo "The product of first 10 numbers is $prod.<br>";
?>
```

The output of which will be:

```
The product of first 10 numbers is 3628800.
```

Comment: yes you are correct, it is product and not sum. Not sure where I got that from.

Comment: If I just want to skip the array and do this:<?php
$total = 1;
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
  $total *= $total[$x];
  
}
echo "The product of first 10 numbers is $total.<br>";

?> why am I getting a 0 instrad of 3628800?

Comment: What's `$total[$x]` supposed to refer to if there's no array? You probably meant `<?php 
$total = 1; 
for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) { 
 $total *= $x; 
}
echo "The product of first 10 numbers is $total.<br>"; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Please note I have not tested this code, but I'm sure it should work.

```
<?php
  $numbers = range(1, 10);
  $product = 1;

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); $i++) {
    $product *= $numbers[$i];
  }

  echo 'The product of the first 10 numbers is ' . $product . '<br />';
?>
```

Comment: I just noticed you want the product not the sum :/  Just fixed that.